# Laravel querybuilder select array with raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query that involves selecting the latest date/value of multiple columns. I used mysql's `greatest` function. My question is how can i use or insert it in a querybuilder that has already a select statement.

Here is the query I tried

```
$ses = DB::table('ses_contracts')
    ->join('ses_worker','ses_contracts.id','ses_worker.ses_id')
    ->join('corporates','corporates.id','ses_contracts.outsourcer')
    ->select([
        'corporates.corpname as outsourcer',
        'ses_contracts.outsourcer_manager_name as manager_name',
        'ses_worker.worker_name as worker_name',
        'ses_worker.sesnum1 as sesnum1',
        'ses_worker.sesnum2 as sesnum2',
        'ses_contracts.work_date1 as start',

        // this is the one i want the max_date for the 6 columns.
        DB::raw('SELECT GREATEST (work_date1,work_date2,work_date3,work_date4,work_date5,work_date6) as end from ses_contracts') 
       // end
    ])
    ->get();

die($ses);
```

The partial result is this one

```
{
    "outsourcer": "㈱daOn",
    "manager_name": "黄",
    "worker_name": "4",
    "sesnum1": "MS-JAN-",
    "sesnum2": 1,
    "start": "2021-10-29"
}
```

What I want is

```
{
    "outsourcer": "㈱daOn",
    "manager_name": "黄",
    "worker_name": "4",
    "sesnum1": "MS-JAN-",
    "sesnum2": 1,
    "start": "2021-10-29",
    "end": "2021-10-30" // supposed oct 30 is latest date of the 6 columns
}
```

When I try the query in mysql or in `DB::select` statement. It works. I just dont know how to add it in an existing select. Hope someone can help. Thanks guys.

Comment: Change `->get()` to `->toSql()` to see the actual query being run, and adjust as necessary. You might just need to remove the extra `SELECT` in `DB::raw()`, since that's already in a `->select()` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `selectRaw`.

```
$ses = DB::table('ses_contracts')
    ->join('ses_worker', 'ses_contracts.id', 'ses_worker.ses_id')
    ->join('corporates', 'corporates.id', 'ses_contracts.outsourcer')
    ->select([
        'corporates.corpname as outsourcer',
        'ses_contracts.outsourcer_manager_name as manager_name',
        'ses_worker.worker_name as worker_name',
        'ses_worker.sesnum1 as sesnum1',
        'ses_worker.sesnum2 as sesnum2',
        'ses_contracts.work_date1 as start'
    ])
    ->selectRaw('GREATEST(ses_contracts.work_date1, ses_contracts.work_date2, ses_contracts.work_date3, ses_contracts.work_date4, ses_contracts.work_date5, ses_contracts.work_date6) as end')
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods